# Can't install debian because installer doesn't parse IP correctly?

Tags: apt, proxy, debian-installer

I am trying to install debian on Virtual box using `debian-7.8.0-amd64-netinst.iso`
When I insert my proxy server `http://192.168.2.2:3128`, it says the installer failed to access the mirror. However on my host operating system (Ubuntu 14.04), with wireshark open, I can see the request is indeed going out and returning a list of hashes and gz files, so I believe I have virtual box configured correctly (using NAT mode).

When I switch into tty4 (which shows the error console), it says

```
"Failed to fetch http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy/main/i18n/Translation-en Cannot initiate the connection to 3128:80 (0.0.12.56). - connect (22: Invalid argument)
```

So I believe it is failing to parse the host portion of the proxy server and it thinks the port is the ip. Is my understanding correct?

I have also tried

```
export http_proxy="192.168.2.2:3128"
export https_proxy="192.168.2.2:3128"
export ftp_proxy="192.168.2.2:3128"
```

Other things I found was to add the proxy into `/etc/apt/apt.conf`, but as this is still at the installation stage, the apt directory doesn't exist.

How can I correctly specify my proxy?

Comment: This sounds like a bug, but a slightly surprising one, if it *is* a bug. One workaround is to try to install without accessing the internet and fix up the network connection later. I'm not sure if that is possible with a netinst though. If it does install, it would be a pretty minimal system.

Comment: What happens if you use `http://192.168.2.2:3128/`, with a slash at the end?

Comment: AARRggh, that appears to have fixed the problem.
Thanks
If you place this as an answer, I can mark it as answered.

Comment: Hah, that's pretty nutty. @AG, I recommend you submit a bug report about this. Installation reports are requested, anyway.

Comment: @AG which one worked? The `/` or installing without internet? O.o

Comment: @muru clearly, adding the trailing slash. Which, imo, is screwy.

Comment: It is a bug and it was supposed to be fixed: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=260626

Comment: @umeboshi Fixed 10 years ago, if I read the dates correctly.

Comment: @muru, that's what I meant about supposed to be fixed.  I just tried to reproduce on netboot install both wheezy and jessie and did not need trailing slash for my apt-cacher proxy.  Something else is wrong and the trailing slash answer doesn't sound accurate anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `http://192.168.2.2:3128/` with a trailing slash.

Without examining the `debian-installer` code, I can't say why it works, and from force of habit I have always entered the proxy server that way (even when using hostnames).

Comment: Good habits die hard...  ;-)

Comment: `export http_proxy="localhost:3128"` won't work  and 
`export http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3128/"` will work, so we need add http://, thanks for the tip